# Pyspark save RDD to Cassandra

Tags: python, apache-spark, cassandra, pyspark, datastax-startup

I have an RDD(test_rdd) as below

```
[
{'user_lname': u'TEst1', 'user_id': u'2aa8ae30-c0e5-48bb-ab16-a2ed2e78c8c3', 'user_phone': u'1234567890', 'user_fname': u'TestingTesting2', 'amount': 1222,’event_timestamp': u’2016-09-29T07:49:50.866+00:00’}, 

{'user_lname': u'TEst2', 'user_id': u'2aa8ae30-c0e5-48bb-ac16-a2ed2e78c8c3', 'user_phone': u'1234567891', 'user_fname': u'TestingTesting', 'amount': 12,’event_timestamp': u’2016-10-27T07:49:50.866+00:00’},

{'user_lname': u'TEst3', 'user_id': u'2aa8ae30-c1e5-48bb-ab16-a2ed2e78c8c3', 'user_phone': u'1234567892', 'user_fname': u'TestingTesting3', 'amount': 122,’event_timestamp': u’2016-09-27T07:49:50.866+00:00'}
]
```

I want to save the above RDD to a cassandra table.
I get the below error when I use

```
test_rdd.saveToCassandra("keyspace1","table1")
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):     File "/var/spark/test/k.py",
>   line 179, in 
>       parsed_data.saveToCassandra("keyspace1","table1")    AttributeError: 'PipelinedRDD' object has no attribute
>   'saveToCassandra'

Answer (score 0):

Either

- follow the instructions for [`pyspark-cassandra`](https://github.com/TargetHolding/pyspark-cassandra#using-with-pyspark)
- and `import pyspark_cassandra`

or

- follow the instructions for the official [`spark-cassandra-connector`](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/master/doc/0_quick_start.md#prerequisites)
- convert to `DataFrame` (`toDF`)
- write `Dataframe`

  ```
  df.write.format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra").options(
    table=table, keyspace=keyspace
  ).save()
  ```

Comment: Thank you. I used the 2nd method.  
What is the difference between pyspark-cassandra and spark-cassandra-connector.